# Help with differentiation of natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Find $\;\dfrac{dy}{dx}\;$ given $y=\frac{\ln(8x)}{8x}$.

The answer is $\;\dfrac{1-\ln(8x)}{8x^2}\;$.

Can you show the process of how this is worked?

Thanks.

Comment: quotient rule..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we can use the **quotient rule** and the chain rule:

**Quotient rule:** $\quad$ If $y = \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, then $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}\tag{(1) quotient rule}$$

$\displaystyle f(x) = \ln(8x), \; f'(x) = \frac 1{8x}\cdot \frac d{dx}(8x) =  \dfrac 8{8x} = \dfrac 1x\quad\text{by chain rule}$

$\displaystyle  g(x) = 8x, \; g'(x) = 8.$

Now, just substitute each of $f(x), g(x), f'(x), g'(x), \text{and} g^2(x) = (8x)^2$ into $(1)$, simplify, and you're done!

$$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{(8x)\frac{1}{x} - \left(\ln(8x)\right)\cdot 8}{64x^2} = \dfrac{(1 - \ln(8x))}{8x^2}$$

Comment: thanks for the step-by-step

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Yes, @Ross Thanks for catching the typo!!

Comment: @amWhy: always gracious! +1

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches here.  The most straightforward way is to apply the [quotient rule](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quotient%20rule.&t=ff3tb01).

That is, given $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$:
$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)\cdot h(x) - g(x)\cdot h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

Or, in words: "bottom times the derivative of the top, minus the top times the derivative of the bottom; all over the bottom squared."

So, we have that the "top" is $\ln 8x$.  The derivative of that is $\frac{1}{x}$, applying the chain rule and the derivative of natural log.

The bottom is $8x$.  The derivative of this is $8$.  (just a power rule)

We plug into the quotient rule:
$$f'(x) = \frac{(8x)\frac{1}{x} - \Big(\ln(8x)\Big)8}{(8x)^2}$$

Simplifying:
$$f'(x) = \frac{8 - 8\ln(8x)}{(8x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1 - \ln(8x)}{8x^2}$$

This is the [correct answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20ln%288x%29/%288x%29).

EDIT: I forgot I mentioned that there were two approaches!  The other approach is to re-write the problem using properties of exponents, and apply the product rule:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{8}x^{-1}\ln(8x)$$
(Differentiate with the product rule--it's a good practice.  You should end up with the same function as above.)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d(ln(x))}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$, you mean this?

Comment: Yes, I know that's the derivative of ln, but when I applied it to the whole problem my answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the quotient rule: $$\frac{1}{8}\left[\frac{x\cdot \frac{1}{x}-1\cdot\ln(8x)}{x^2}\right].$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would help this answer to include more details and to show how this would work given the OP had issues with it. In its current form, this is better as a comment. Regards

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{\ln(8x)}{8x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{8x \frac{d(\ln(8x))}{dx} - \ln(8x) \frac{d(8x)}{dx}}{(8x)^2}$$

Then use the following facts:

$$\frac{d \ln(ax)}{dx}=\frac{a}{ax}$$

and

$$\frac{d (ax)}{dx}=a$$

Answer (score 0):

$h(x)=\frac{\ln(8x)}{8x}$.

Use the Quotient Rule. That is given $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, its derivative is $\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{(g(x))^2}$

$h'(x)=\frac{(1/x)(8x)-(8)(\ln(8x))}{64x^2}$

$=\frac{8-8\ln8x}{64x^2}=\frac{8(1-\ln8x)}{64x^2}=\frac{1-\ln x}{8x^2}$